# How to make ExtJS closabel component

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

My requirement is that I need one container with "X" in top right corner of container. On click of X the container should get disappear. Logic is not a problem for me.I want a container with "X" on top right.

Here is what I am trying

```
var myBtn  =Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'x',
        handler: function() {
            /*this.container.component.removeAll();
            this.container.component.updateLayout();*/
        }
    });  
    myFields.push(me.getField(selectedRecord));
    myFields.push(btn);
    me.add({
        xtype: 'container',
        margin: '0 6',
        draggable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        height: 50,
        items: dropField,
        listeners: {
            render: function() {
                new Ext.dd.DragDrop(this.body, "myGrp");
            }
        }
    });


in `getField` method I am getting "textfield component". Can anybody help me to get that closable container. I am trying with panel but there I am getting only "X". textfield component is missing.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [panel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html) component with [closable](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-closable) property